# Understanding XML Schema Data types

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm working through an XML assignment and I'm not sure if I'm doing this part right. 
Its asking to :

• grantType, based on the ID data type and following the regular expression pattern
“[A-Z]{6}-\d{4}-\d{2}”

• fundingType based on the string data type and limited to the following values:
federal, state, local, and private

The part that is throwing me off is when it is asking to follow the regular expression pattern am I suppose to input the reg pattern or is it suppose to be like I have it below?

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<grant grantNum="NIHCCC-4481-05" funding="federal government">

   <title>NIH Clinical Cancer Basic Research Grant</title>
   <agency>National Institute of Health</agency>
   <department>University Hospital Clinical Cancer Center</department>
   <summary>Basic NIH support funding for current and future Phase 1 through
            Phase 3 cancer clinical trials.</summary>
   <initiated>2006-07-01</initiated>
   <expires>2010-06-30</expires>
   <coordinator>Alice Walters</coordinator>

</grant>
```

My Schema:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    xmlns:"http://uhosp.edu/grant/ns"
    targetNamespace="http://uhosp.edu/grant/ns"

 <xs:element name="grant">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="title"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="agency"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="department"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="summary"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:date" name="initiated"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:date" name="expires"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="coordinator"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="grantNum"/>
      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="funding"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the XSD that you need..

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://uhosp.edu/grant/ns"
    targetNamespace="http://uhosp.edu/grant/ns">
    <xs:element name="grant">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="title"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="agency"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="department"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="summary"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:date" name="initiated"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:date" name="expires"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="coordinator"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="grantType" name="grantNum"/>
            <xs:attribute type="fundingType" name="funding"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="fundingType" type="fundingType"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="fundingType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="private"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="local"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="state"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="federal"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="grantType" type="grantType"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="grantType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{6}-\d{4}-\d{2}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a simpleType named grantType, derived from xs:string by restriction using a pattern facet with the regular expression you have given, and then you need to declare the attribute grantNum as having type grantType, rather than type xs:string.